# Spring 5 multiple / partial data models across views

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

What is the best way to code/design things, which are always visible to logged in users, for example things like current cart entries block in kind of shop application using Spring, Hibernate and JSP?
Especially what is the best way to pass data from database and present it to user? Currently I only know how to pass single dedicated data for every page like products in product list page:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/productList")
public String productList(Model model) {
    System.out.println("Requested productList");
    model.addAttribute("products", productService.list());
    return "productList";
}
```

but I also want to present at that page another 'view' with data about current cart entries, like quantity and their names / price when user is logged in. Do you always have to check for it in every request and add 'cart entries' object to ModelAndView instance like:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/productList")
    public String productList(Model model) {
        System.out.println("Requested productList");

        // Check if should add CartEntries data
        model.addAttribute("cartEntries", cartService.list());

        model.addAttribute("products", productService.list());
        return "productList";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the most effective way is to store frequently required data in the Session scoped beans. For example your user add to the cart several items which can be present as `List<Product> productList`. This way will helps you increase database queries and application response time. But if you need pass data which can be changed between request, you should store some ID in database and fetch actual data in each request.